# unable to get response from object<T> From my template function

Tags: c#, .net, api, xamarin.forms, nuget

**Created Delegate for this**

```
public event EventHandler<ResponseViewModel<object>> ResponseAPI = delegate { };
//Created delegates here
```

**Interface which i am using**

```
public event EventHandler<ResponseViewModel<object>> ResponseAPI;
Task<T> ValidateUser<T>(string ApiUrl, IDictionary<string, string> UserInfo);

//Interface created here
```

**Properties for above **
//Properties for the my  ResponseViewModel

```
public class ResponseViewModel<T>
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<ErrorViewModel> Errors { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }

        public ResponseViewModel()
        {
            Result = default(T);
            Errors = new List<ErrorViewModel>();
            Status = null;
        }
    }

    public class ErrorViewModel
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

**This is  my function in Xamarin cross plugin**
//Function which i  have  been created for validate user

```
public async Task<T> ValidateUser<T>(string ApiUrl, IDictionary<string, string> UserInfo)
        {
            ResponseViewModel<object> errorResponse = new ResponseViewModel<object>();
            T response = default(T);
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserInfo);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiUrl);

                StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                
                HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.PostAsync(ApiUrl, content);
                var result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    response = Deserialize<T>(result);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException webex)
            {
                errorResponse.Status = "-2";
                using (WebResponse webResp = webex.Response)
                {
                    errorResponse.Message = webex.Message;
                    var resString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse);
                    response = Deserialize<T>(resString);
                };
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException operationex)
            {
                errorResponse.Status = "-2";
                errorResponse.Message = "Please check your internet connection, and try again later.";
                var resString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse);
                response = Deserialize<T>(resString);
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException jsonException)
            {
                errorResponse.Status = "-2";
                errorResponse.Message = "We are not able to connect to Server. Please try after 
                  sometime.";
                var resString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse);
                response = Deserialize<T>(resString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorResponse.Status = "-2";
                errorResponse.Message = ex.Message;
                var resString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse);
                response = Deserialize<T>(resString);
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(response);
            
        }

        private T Deserialize<T>(string result)
        {
            //Deserialize object here
            var toReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
            return toReturn;
        }


**Sample Project Function Call**
//Passing parameter  from the sample project
CrossEDFSTemplate.Current.ValidateUser<ResponseViewModel<Root>>(ApiUrl, UserData);
```

****Sample Project Properties for api****
//APIs related properties for the get data
public class Data
{
public List lpcIds { get; set; }
public string advisor_id { get; set; }
public string firstname { get; set; }
public string lastname { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
public string phone { get; set; }
}

```
    public class Root
    {
        public string userToken { get; set; }
        public string esCodesVersion { get; set; }
        public object esTermsVersion { get; set; }
        public string appVersion { get; set; }
        public string limIncomeDefinitionsversion { get; set; }
        public string VoiceSubDomainName { get; set; }
        public string userVApiKey { get; set; }
        public string VoiceApiSecret { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
```

****Response Event in Sample Project****
//Created Event here
PluginTemplate.Current.ResponseAPI += Current_ResponseAPI;

```
private void Current_ResponseAPI(object sender, ResponseViewModel<object> e)
        {
            
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("API",e.Message + "Response this is ", "Ok");
                Params.Clear();
                Header.Clear();
            });
        }
```

**I am unable to get response from the Root how could i do this Help me please**

Comment: `Root` doesn't have any methods. How would you get a response from it?

Comment: so  what should i  do now ?? root is my get set property

Comment: The code looks confusing, you can try create a simple demo and elaborate more on what you'd like to achieve.